# No Data When Trying To Display Data From A Database

Tags: php

I have connected to a database and am trying to retrieve data I captured in a form. I know I am missing an endwhile statement but adding it gives errors. What's wrong with my code?

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in .php on line 29**

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = "SELECT * FROM {$Table_2}";

if($Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)){
$tcgname = $row['name'];
$tcgintelligence = $row['intelligence'];
$tcgstrength = $row['strength'];
$tcgspeed = $row['speed'];
$tcgenergy = $row['energy'];
$tcgfighting = $row['fighting']; 
$tcggoogle = $row['google']; 
$tcgbiography = $row['biography']; 

echo $tcgname;
echo $tcgbiography;
echo $tcgintelligence;
echo $tcgstrength;
echo $tcgspeed;
echo $tcgenergy;
echo $tcgfighting;
echo $tcggoogle;
endwhile;
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: endwhile? no idea why it should be missing… you maybe should learn more about PHP before asking here ;-)

Comment: what about your missing `mysqli_select_db()` ? Maybe also add some `or die()` catches in there on your mysqli_xxx functions

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you are missing indentation. It'll work without that, but as it stands it is hard to read. Fix this in your code, and ideally here too.

Comment: @halfer I prefer not to indent code. It's easier for me to follow without indenting. I know this isn't common practice but it's how I work!

Comment: Your questions may, in that case, attract downvotes. I can't fathom at all how it might be easier to read, and should imagine working with other developers might prove rather tricky.

Comment: Try changing `mysqli_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing an endwhile, the syntax is

```
while() {

}
```

or

```
while:

endwhile
```

What is $Table_2?

Comment: $Table_2 is defined in my connect.php script. It's a variable for the name of a database.

Comment: Do I need an endwhile statement?

Comment: I suggest you read up on loops, and php in general before asking for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the database in the connection string, it should be like:

```
$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
```

Anyway what's the error?

The proper syntax for while() {} is:

```
while (expression) {
//instructions
}
```

the syntax for while endwhile is:

```
while (expression):
//instructions
endwhile;
```

Choose one way of using syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it and the endwhile statement. The error is :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in .php on line 29

Comment: Change this line too:
`$Query = "SELECT * FROM {$Table_2}";`
This way you are sure that you pass the value of $Table_2 into the query.
Can you update the code with the endwhile statement, and please post the error line.

Comment: Updated. I used vardump to check the variables and the data is there and will display IF I remove the endwhile statement which I'm sure isn't a good idea.